# Tracking number of downloads in Django

Tags: django

I have a website where I allow people to download files, such as Powerpoint templates that they can reuse.

I added a column to the model that stores information and location of these files called 'Downloads' and in that column I'd like to use it as a counter to track how many times the file has been downloaded.

How would I go about this? Would it be a GET request on the page? Basically I just provide a link to the file and the download starts automatically, so not sure how to relay the fact that the link was clicked back to the model.

Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you create a view that handles the GET request you could put the updating code in that view. If your Django-app is not handling the uploading itself, you can create a view that simply redirects to the download link, after updating the counter in the database.

Answer (score 2):

You have several ways to do this:

- create a custom view, that "proxies" all files, while keeping track of downloads
- create a middleware that does pretty much the same as above, filtering which requests to record
- ..but none of the above will be applicable if you want to count downloads of collected static files, that will be served directly by your http server, without passing through django. In this case, I'd retrieve the downloads count from the webserver logs; have a look if your webserver allows storing logs to database, otherwise I'd create a cron-running scripts that parses the logfiles and stores the count to a db, accessible from your django application.

Answer (score 1):

Like redShadow said you can create a proxie view. This view could serve the files via [mod_xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) (if you are using apache as webserver) and set a counter for the downloads.

Comment: @user1328021 I need this functionality now, did you figure out a way to fix this?